# Display Columns with a Value as List in FMP View

Tags: filemaker

**GIVEN:**
A FMP database that has the following columns in 1 table:

- Student
- *other data to be displayed*
- Test1_Grade
- Test2_Grade
- Test3_Grade
- Test4_Grade
- Test5_Grade

**WHEN:**

**StudentA** only gets grades for tests 1, 3, and 5 and

**StudentB** only get grades for tests 1 and 4

**HOW:** would you display only the test fields that have a value as a list for each student in a view?

Ex:

**StudentA**

... other data to be displayed ...

- Test1_Grade A
- Test3_Grade B-
- Test5_Grade B

... other data to be displayed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the grades in a related table and use a portal to enter/show the relevant grades.

Then you could make a calculation field using the List function to retrieve the related values.

If that’s not an option you could make a calculation field using simple Case structures to include only data from the fields that are relevant or not empty and use that for display.